# Weird and unexpected behaviour while using http post and set a class in Blazor. Why?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

This is a very simple login screen...

```cs
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject User user
@page "/loginSignup"
<div class="text-center">
Logged: [@user.Name]

    <EditForm class="form-signin" model="@loginForm" OnSubmit="@DoLogin">
        <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="loginForm.email" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus />
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="loginForm.password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">
            <a @onclick='() => mode ="signup"' @onclick:preventDefault href="">Not registered ? Create an Account</a>
        </p>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {
    private string mode = "login";
    public LoginFormModel loginForm = new LoginFormModel();

    private async void DoLogin()
    {
        var body = new LoginFormModel { email = loginForm.email, password = loginForm.password };
        var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:1337/customers/login", body);
        User userSet = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<User>();
        user.Name = "tst";
        Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
    }

    public class LoginFormModel
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I submit, the line `Logged: [@user.Name]` on html will not show anything, but the console will display tst. If I press the submit again, then it works as expected and this will display TST on `Logged: [@user.Name]` and on the console.

I decided to comment all the lines at DoLogin and just left:

```cs
user.Name = "tst";
Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
```

In this fashion, this works as expected. If I press the submit, I can see Tst on console and on the screen. It means that my http call is messing the render in some how. Why ?

More details:

Core5, injected user is a Singleton class.

Comment: p.s. I think `DoLogin` should return `Task`. edit: on second though, try that first. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the return type of your async method: you return a `void` which is non-blocking. [The docs about this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types)

Non-blocking means the caller will not await finishing the call and immediately continue with the next statements. I.e. in this case the render engine will probably trigger a component update while the `DoLogin` is still running and the output values have not been set.

To properly use await/async, you need to return an awaitable task from the method.

---

old answer (not fully valid anymore):

(I think) the problem is that you update an external (injected) object. Thus the Razor Component instance will not detect that anything is updated locally and not refresh.

I think the best solution would be to replace the name with a local variable

```cs
Logged: [UserName]

...
@code{
    private string UserName {get;set;}
...
    private async Task DoLogin()
    {
        ...
        UserName = "tst"; // or =user.Name;
    }    
}
```

An alternative would be to trigger a component update using `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);`

Comment: Same Result...with it makes more weird ! So, it's not about a singleton class...this can happen even in a very basic situation.

Comment: @MarcoJr did you change the `void` return type of `DoLogin` to `Task`?

Comment: Sorry...I did;t...now I did...and YES ! It works !!! Let me ask you...What is the explanation for that ? I really appreciate the solution, but it's always good to extract a knowledge. Thanks in advance !